# Two generic types in a extension method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, extension-methods

**Right now my code is code looks something like this: (Simplified!)**

```
public static IQueryable<T> ListedProducts<T,V>(this IQueryable<T> collection) 
     where T : ProductCollection<V> 
     where V: Product
{
     return collection.Where(x => x.Listed == true);
}
```

And to use it i have to define both Types like this:

```
SomeCollection.ListedProducts<BikeCollection,BikeProduct>()
```

---

**This is how i would like it to be:**

I want to be able to write something lkie this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ListedProducts<T<V>>(this IQueryable<T<V>> collection)
     where T : ProductCollection<V>
{
     return collection.Where(x => x.Listed == true);
}
```

Where i only needed to write:

```
SomeCollection.ListedProducts()
```

I think it's possible since "SomeCollection" contains both types for the generic ListedProducts method.

---

Hope my question is clear enough and there is a solution :)

---

**UPDATE**

There seem to be many fustrations on how my code is set up, so here are some of the classes (simplified)

**ProductCollection**

```
public class ProductCollection<T> where T : Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CollectionName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<T> Products { get; set; }
    public bool Listed { get; set; }
}
```

**ProductCollection**

```
public class BikeCollection : ProductCollection<BikeProduct>
{
   //Bike specific properties
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're really looking for anything that is functionally identical to the first solution, but that allows for generic argument inference when called, yes?

Comment: Yeah, sounds about right!

Comment: Just a side note, instead of `x => x.Listed == true`, you can also use `x => x.Listed`, because `x.Listed` (a bool) returns the same value as `x.Listed == true` (which is also a bool)

Comment: Heh yah i know ProgramFox but i like i like to do it anyway for readability, it's easier to spot that it's a boolean when you glance over the code.

Comment: I read your first version of your comment aswell @Servy, problem with it was that was that it "SomeCollection<T>" is just the base class of the "SomeCollection" object, so i would get the wrong type returned from the ListedProducts method

Comment: Would something like `someCollection.Get().ListedProducts()` look good for you? It will open some possibilities to resolve types automatically...

Comment: Yeah that would be fine aswell :)

Comment: Am I right in inferring that `BikeCollection : ProductCollection<Bike>`?

Comment: @AndrewCoonce One would assume `ProcuctCollection<BikeProduct>`

Comment: @Servy: I'm struggling with whether `SomeCollection` is a collection of `ProductCollection<BikeProduct>` objects, or if it is a *single* `ProductCollection<BikeProduct>` object. As it stands, this might be an ill-formed question, but it's definitely unclear.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce `SomeCollection` would need to be a query (not collection) of collections of products (`IQueryable<ProductCollection<BikeProduct>>`), not a single collection, else it wouldn't compile.

Comment: public class SomeCollection : ProductCollection<BikeProduct> (SomeCollection might be better named as BikeCollection)

Comment: @BjarkeCK Then your code won't compile.  Your method `ListedProducts` takes a query of collections of products, not just a collection of products.

Comment: @Servy: That's what I was afriad BjarkeCK was going to say... yeah, this is malformed.

Comment: Okay so you guys say my code wont compile? Even in my first example? Btw, thanks for looking in to it so deeply!

Comment: Do you have `ProductCollection<Product>` which is queryable, or you have queryable collection of product collections `IQueryable<ProductCollection<Product>>`? According to `T` argument constraint you have latter, but that looks very strange to me

Comment: @lazyberezovsky i have a  queryable collection of ProductCollection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Based on your recent updates, I'd suggest the following:

Recommendations: change `ProductCollection<T>` so that it implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public class ProductCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
  where T : Product
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string CollectionName { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<T> Products { get; set; }
  public bool Listed { get; set; }

  // This is all it takes to implement IEnumerable<T>
  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()   { return this.Products.GetEnumerator(); }
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return this.Products.GetEnumerator(); }
}
```

Then, you can change your extension in the following way:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ListedProducts<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) 
  where T : Product
{
  return collection.Where(x => x.Listed == true);
}
```

This allows you to do things like:

```
// WHERE  BikeCollection : ProductCollection<BikeProduct>
// AND    BikeProduct : Product
var someCollection = new BikeCollection();

// What you want
var listedBikes1 = someCollection.ListedProducts();

// Another way you can do it, if ProductCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
var listedBikes2 =
  from product in someCollection
  where product.Listed
  select product;
```

Comment: In your example T Should be of type ProductCollection, not Product :(

Comment: @BjarkeCK No, because your collection is *not* a query of collections of products, it's just a collection/query of products

Comment: @Andrew note that such a method would apply to any query of products, not just products that were `ProductCollection` queries.  That may or may not be an issue.

Comment: @BjarkeCK: As Servy says, your `ProductCollection` class is-a `Queryable` collection of `Product` objects.

Comment: Aaaaah, i think i get it now, going to try it out.

Comment: @BjarkeCK: And to Servy's note regarding the use of `IQueryable<T>` instead of `ProductCollection<T>` as the extended class/interface: I've intentionally made this available to all queries to allow LINQ chaining.

Comment: I thought i got it... I've updated my question with some more details, don't know if it helps... i'm not sure why i need to implement the IQueryabe interface in my ProductCollection :/

Comment: @BjarkeCK: I updated my answer, providing more details about why you would want to implement `IEnumerable` (or `IQueryable`, but you only ~need~ to do the former)

Answer (score 0):

Whould this work?

```
public static class StaticFunctions
{
    public static IQueryable<ProductCollection<T>> ListedProducts<T>(this IQueryable<ProductCollection<T>> collection)
    where T : Product
    {
        return collection.Where(x => x.Listed == true);
    }
}

public class ProductCollection<T>
    where T:Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CollectionName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<T> Products { get; set; }
    public bool Listed { get; set; }
}

public class BikeCollection : ProductCollection<BikeProduct>
{
    //Bike specific collection
}

public class BikeProduct:Product
{
    //Can be anything
}

public class Product
{
    //Can be anything
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         IQueryable<ProductCollection<BikeProduct>> titi = new EnumerableQuery<ProductCollection<BikeProduct>>(new List<ProductCollection<BikeProduct>>());

        titi.ListedProducts();

        var toto = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) based on the edits from the OP, he doesn't actually have a query of collections of products, he just has collections of products.  2) The issue with this code, assuming the OP did actually have a query of collections, is that the caller is losing the information about the type of the collection.  The object goes from an `IQueryable<BikeCollection>` to an `IQueryable<ProductCollection<BikeProduct>>`, which means the caller can no longer access the `BikeCollection` specific values.  The additional generic argument allows it to maintain the proper type for the caller.

Comment: Oups, I haven't seen the issue